# How to reinject scanned mail into the queue using sendmail

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I would like to pass incoming mail using `virtual_transport` to a transport `spamassassin` (main.cf: `virtual_transport=spamassassin`) and then reinject the scanned mail into postfix using sendmail.

The transport looks like this:

```
spamassassin unix   -    n     n   -   -    pipe
    flags=hu user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/bin/spamc -u ${recipient} -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

This should be possible acording to the [postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/QSHAPE_README.html#maildrop_queue):

> High volume sites should avoid using "simple" content filters that
>   re-inject scanned mail via Postfix sendmail(1) and postdrop(1).

With my current sendmail call `/usr/sbin/sendmail -f ${sender} ${recipient}`, the mail loops by getting passed back into the queue and then back to spamassassin and so on.

From my understanding of the postfix documentation, mail delivered using postfix `sendmail` is dropped in the `maildrop` directory and then picked up using `pickup`. I tried to append a `-o virtual_transport=dovecot` to the pickup transport to avoid the queue, but this didn't help. (Those options can only get appended to smtp transports I suppose).

How can I reinject mail scanned with spamassassin back into the queue for final delivery without causing a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I reinject mail scanned with spamassassin back into the queue for final delivery without causing a loop?

NO You can't

#### Explanation

I understand the reason you use `virtual_transport` to pipe email into Spam Assassin. You only want to scan the email  intended to your `virtual_mailbox_domain`. Unfortunately it doesn't follow the *recommended* [setup for simple content filter](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#simple_filter) that using `content_filter` parameter instead `virtual_transport`.

#### Why I can't pass `virtual_transport` to pickup or smtpd?

Generally, here the email journey across postfix code

```
Input  --> cleanup --> qmgr --> Output 
*smtpd                          *local     
*pickup                         *virtual
*qmqpd                          *smtp
                                *lmtp
                                *pipe
```

In `cleanup` daemon, postfix will 'route' your email, whether they are belong to virtual, local, smtp or other transports. One exception is when non-blank `content_filter` parameter was passed into input service (`smtpd`, `pickup`, `qmqpd`). When this happened, postfix will override the message route and send the email into `content_filter` instead.

Another note, by default all postfix service was get parameter value from `main.cf` unless you override it by using *-o parameter=value*  on `master.cf`. But not every parameter in `man 5 postconf` used by a service. For example, *content_filter* only used by `pickup`, `smtpd` and `qmqpd` so you can put *-o content_filter=amavis:[127.0.0.1:10025* on them. Another example, it is not sensible to put *-o smtp_bind_address* in `smtpd` as this parameter only used in `smtp` service.

The same argument can be applied to your question, "why I can pass *-o virtual_transport* in `pickup`?"

#### So here are the several alternatives for your setup

- Use `content_filter` as explained in postfix documentation. The downside is you also scan the email that relayed outside your domain.
- Use `content_filter` [via ACCESS table and FILTER action](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#dynamic_filter). With this way, you can selectively scan the incoming email. <s>Unfortunately you must enlist your `virtual domain` again in that table.</s>. You can avoid it by carefully placing ACCESS table after `permit_mynetworks`, `permit_sasl_authenticated`. With this way, outgoing email will be already permitted and you only scan incoming email. ([Credit to OP comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/688250/how-to-reinject-scanned-mail-into-the-queue-using-sendmail/688257?noredirect=1#comment848408_688257) :) )
- Using [Postfix Multiple Instance](http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html). With this way, you can keep the `virtual_transport` parameter and spamc will inject the email to your second instance. And then you can define different `virtual_transport` in different instance. But it's a bit overkill if you want to keep your setup simple.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I got a question about the [simple filter setup](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#simple_filter): How does this not end in a loop without `content_filter=` in the pickup transport?

Comment: Because you don't specify content_filter in `main.cf`, then content_filter was blank. You only specify content_filter in `smtpd`, not `pickup`

Comment: Ah, right. Shouldn't `content_filter` via `ACCESS` table and `FILTER` action work even without another complete list of the virtual domains using the following setup: `smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    check_sender_access regexp:$config_directory/apply_content_filter,
    permit` and a `apply_content_filter` with content `/.*/ FILTER spamassassin:dummy`? Or are there any caveats/downsides to this?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Outgoing email will be permitted by `permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated`, so you are only filter virtual domain.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Great, I've edited the answer to include your comment ;)

Comment: One more note: I couldn't find very much information in regard to "final destination" transports in postfix and [this](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/relocation-of-virtual-transport-settings-to-master-cf-service-tp3789p3796.html) suggests a different reason why `virtual_transport` can't be changed using `-o virtual_transport=..`. Can you elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: See my updated answer :)